# Unity launcher dissapears

Tags: unity, launcher

When you open two or more windows of the same program, the icon in the Unity Laucher shows two or more arrows telling you there are more instances opened. And then when you click on the icon all the winodws are displayed so you can choose one of them right??

THIS IS NOT HAPPENING TO ME !!! I just updataed my Ubuntu 14.04 [sudo apt-get upgrade]

When I click on the icon, the screen blinks and my Unity Launcher disspaears D:

What can I do ?? HEEEEEEEELP !!!

Comment: Here is how I solved it: Just needed to reset Unity. For this, I needed to install unity-tweak-tool [sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily][sudo apt-get update][sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool] Then reset Unity: [unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity]